# Is there anyway to flush data of a csv file without actually closing it?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, flush

My code is,

```
import csv
myfile1=open('data1.csv','a')
mywriter=csv.writer(myfile1)
myfile=open('data1.csv','r+')
myreader=csv.reader(myfile)
for i in myreader:
    print(i)
mywriter.writerow(['123','2021-04-18'])
myfile.flush()
print('hello world')
myfile.seek(0)
for j in myreader:
    print(j)
```

initially it works well for and prints everything in my file during the first loop. Then i enter new row which is '123','2021-04-18' and i even tried flushing it but when i print the contents of the file again it doesn't show up.
[output for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Dzd.png). Is there anyway to solve this.     EDIT:I've also tried reading again after seek(0),

```
import csv
myfile1=open('data1.csv','a')
mywriter=csv.writer(myfile1)
myfile=open('data1.csv','r+')
myreader=csv.reader(myfile)
for i in myreader:
    print(i)
mywriter.writerow(['123','2021-04-18'])
myfile.flush()
print('hello world')
myfile.seek(0)
myreader1=csv.reader(myfile)
for j in myreader1:
    print(j)
```

the output can be [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lnDK.png).

Comment: If i give mywriter.flush() it gives "AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'flush'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code in the question, data is being added to `myfile1` via `mywriter`.  Therefore we need to flush `myfile1` to make the data available to `myfile`.

```py
import csv

myfile1 = open("data1.csv", "a")
mywriter = csv.writer(myfile1)
myfile = open("data1.csv", "r+")
myreader = csv.reader(myfile)
for i in myreader:
    print(i)
mywriter.writerow(["123", "2021-04-18"])

myfile1.flush()

print("hello world")
myfile.seek(0)
for j in myreader:
    print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you `seek(0)` you need to read the file again. Right now you are looking at old data.

Comment: Please show that code in your question, by appending.